# CKeditor radio vertical

Tags: javascript, radio-button, ckeditor

I am trying to make the radio button vertical using CKEditor's 4 api.
I saw [this](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5094) ticket from the official website, but in my version of CKEditor I don't have the Dialogui folder since it's an optimized version. I have then dowloaded a source version form the [builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) but when i use this version my custom plugins aren't working anymore. I get those kind of error for a piece of code which I know is correct.

```
TypeError: CKEDITOR.dialogCommand is not a constructor     
editor.addCommand( 'lien' , new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'lienDialog',{ allowedContent: 'a[title,!href,id,onclick,target]'
        } ) );
```

so my question is how can I make my radio buttons vertical using the optimized version of CKEditor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok well I found in the optimized code the line to change to make it work : it's at line 434 more or less depend of version I think i just change this

```
new CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.hbox(b,e,d,h);
```

by this

```
if(a.labelLayout=='vertical')new CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.vbox(b,e,d,h);else new CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.hbox(b,e,d,h);
```

hope it could help someone.

Comment: One clarification - this change should be made around line 434 in the ckeditor.js file.

Comment: Anyone tested this with IE9? I have only IE10 and up, and it works for those, but one of the ckeditor tickets mentioned some problem with IE9. And this one liner patch is still not in ckeditor 4.3.x!

Comment: I mean in this ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5094, they say "IE9 may have a problem when laying out the dialog - see case #8364."

Comment: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8364 is closed since it is caused by user fiddling with the code. But I think it's very lame that ckeditor cannot align the radio button vertically. Seriously?